# CPR Kant's three proofs of god

Tags: critique-of-pure-reason

A616/B644:  "There is something exceedingly remarkable in the fact that when one presupposes something existing, one can find no way around the con clusion that something also exists necessarily. . . . if I assume the concept of anything I like, then I find that its existence can never be represented by me as absolutely necessary, and that whatever may exist, nothing hinders me from thinking its non-being; hence although for the existing in general I must assume something necessary.

Is he saying that any particular thing, while it exists contingently, nevertheless demonstrates absolute necessary existence?  Is there somewhere a contradiction in this?

Comment: On the contrary: he says that there is no way to deduce the existence of some "instance" of a concept from the concept itself. The is nothing contradictory in the concept of unicorns, nevertheless there are no unicorns.

Comment: He is saying that, generally, something existing leads us to *also* posit something existing necessarily. On the other hand, thinking of any particular thing as existing lets us think of it as non-existing as well. This *would* be a contradiction if necessity concerned the things themselves, but it does not. It only concerns tendencies of reason: "*for everything given as existing to seek something that is necessary*" and "*to consider everything perceived as necessarily conditioned*", hence *not* absolutely necessary. There is nothing contradictory in reason having two conflicting tendencies.

Comment: Thank you Mauro and Conifold for responding.  I found interesting in the quote the interplay of contingency and necessity.  The concepts themselves seem to require each other, and this is maybe that necessary tendency of reason, but nothing is objectively necessary, i.e, no particular object is necessary.